# Distinguish page load and Export to Excel in CRM 2015

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm writing a plugin which will be triggered when user press "Export to Excel" button. I'm currently hooking it up to "RetrieveMultiple" message. However, the same message is also triggered when the page is loaded. Is there anyway that I can distinguish between a page load message and a "Export to Excel" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a special message in the SDK for exporting to Excel that you could register your plugin against.  I can think of two options:

1. Override the Export to Excel button in the application ribbon to call a custom JavaScript function. Your function would do whatever you want to do and then optionally pass the request on to the normal Export to Excel function.
2. Find some way to distinguish the RetrieveMultiple message (as you are attempting to do).

   - Download  [CRM Snoop](http://www.sonomapartners.com/tools/crmsnoop), install it in your org, register it against RetrieveMultiple for your entity, turn it on [(basic usage)](http://www.sonomapartners.com/tools/crmsnoop/basicusage), and then trigger an export to excel.  It will make it really easy to see the RetrieveMultiple request and inspect all of its properties.  Poke around to see if anything jumps out at you that would allow you to distinguish it as an export to excel.  I don't suspect you'll find anything, but it's definitely worth a shot.
   - Side note, I'm a smidge surprised CRM doesn't bypass the plugin execution pipeline for exporting to excel as it does for reports and charts.

Comment: Your 1st option is what I would do if I cannot distinguish those RetrieveMultiple messages, but I want to keep it as the last resort. I will try CRM Snoop and update back if I find anything.

Comment: I did find some differences between page load and export to excel. I've posted my finding as an answer. Thank you very much for your advice, sorry that I don't have enough rep to upvote you though.

Answer (score 2):

Following Polshgiant's advice, I have installed CRM Snoop and found 3 differences between page load and export to excel.

- At page load, context depth is 1, while at export to excel, context depth is 2.
- At page load, ParentContext is null, while at export to excel, ParentContext is not null and contains the following parameters: "View", "FetchXml", "LayoutXml", "QueryApi", "QueryParameters".
- When export to excel, the message of ParentContext is clearly labeled as "ExportToExcel".

Using those differences, I've been able to trigger my plugin at and only at export to excel event.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad you were able to make progress! One thing to be careful for is that many other messages or events in the system could result in some of those same parameters. Have your plugin write messages to the Plugin Trace Log (google around for info) and periodically review the log to make sure it doesn't run when you don't expect it to. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I found out that when using export to excel, the message of ParentContext is clearly labeled as "ExportToExcel", I still don't know how I missed it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExportToExcel and ExportDynamicToExcel "virtual" messages in your plugin registered for RetrieveMultiple:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var executionContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IPluginExecutionContext>();
    var parentContext = executionContext.ParentContext;
    if (parentContext != null &&
        (parentContext.MessageName == "ExportToExcel" ||
         parentContext.MessageName == "ExportDynamicToExcel"))
    {
        // Place your logic here
    }
}
```